# Python - change text in string by random from a list

Tags: python

I want to write a loop function that go through each letter in my list called original.

```
original = ['ABCD', 'DCBA', 'AAAA', 'AABB']
letters  = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 

p = 1

for o in original: # loop through the original list
    for i in range(0,len(o)): # loop through each letter in selected list

        if random.randint(1,10) == p: #if this gives me the probability that is met
        # I want to change the current letter on the current index to 
        # something else different from the letter list by random (maybe random.choice)
```

Im new to python please can you advice.
I dont want to use class or any other library but random please

Comment: Your sentence cut off: " that go through each letter in my...".  What's the rest?

Comment: o[i] = random.choice(letters) should do it

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman I tried that random.choice(letters) but it can give me the same letter as original - how to make sure that random.choice from the list of letters that isn't the same as the original?

Comment: @PeddiePooh Let me write an answer for that, also my above comment is wrong but close

Comment: @DarrylG sorry I'm not sure how to edit it.

Comment: @PeddiePooh--um, you don't see a way to edit your question?  If it is a small continuation you can add as a comment and I'll update your question.

Comment: @DarrylG found it and amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the zero in

```
for i in range(0, len(o))
```

is redundant. You want to give random.choice a list of letters that include everything in letters minus the current letter. The fastest way I can think of doing this is with a set:

```
newletters = list(set(letters).difference(o[i])
```

Now you have a list that includes all the letters in "letters" except for the letter at o[i].

To assign the letter (after you get it from random.choice), turn your "original" word into a list:

```
o_list = list(o)
```

and assign it as

```
l = random.choice(newletters)
o_list[i] = l
new_word = "".join(o_list)
```

As for actually inserting that new word back into your list of originals, you would have to know the index of the old word - I would use enumerate to do this:

```
original = ['ABCD', 'DCBA', 'AAAA', 'AABB']
letters  = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 

p = 1
for index, o in enumerate(original): # loop through the original list
    for i in range(len(o)): # loop through each letter in selected list
        if random.randint(1,10) == p:
            newletters = list(set(letters).difference(o[i])
            o_list = list(o)
            l = random.choice(newletters)
            o_list[i] = l
            new_word = "".join(o_list)
            original[index] = new_word
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can not modify strings at all. You can get letters by index, select specific strings, but not modify them. To change the said list you can use `original.pop(o)` and add the said edited string in the list with `original.append('AB" + random.choice(letters) + 'C'` as you said. To be more clear: you use `list.append(element)` to add element to list and you use `list.pop(element)` to remove element from list. Again, you can never edit strings in python, you can only create new ones and store the edited old ones, for example, `new_string = old_string[:4]`, this particular code will store all the characters in old_string, up to index 4 into the new string. Really hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to update original

```
import random

original = ['ABCD', 'DCBA', 'AAAA', 'AABB']
letters  = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 

p = 1

for i, o in enumerate(original):
    new_letters = []     # updated letters for word o 
    for c in o:
      if random.randint(1,10) == p:
        t = letters[:]   # copy of letters
        t.remove(c)      # remove letter from copy (so letters remains unchanged)
        new_letters.append(random.choice(t))  # choice over remaining letters
      else:
        new_letters.append(c)

    original[i] = ''.join(new_letters)        # convert newsletters list to string 
                                              # and replace in original

print(original)
```